# Handle Back Button in each scene navigation in react Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, scene

I have included the back button as a image in the scene which i want back button, I want to perform the back action in the component, Is it possible?

```
<Scene key=“Courses”  icon={TabIcon}  iconName=“book” backButtonImage={require(‘./app/icons/back.png’)}>
           <Scene key=“CourseList” component={CourseList}  title=“Courses”  navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarColor} titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleColor} />
           <Scene key=“levels” component={levels}  barButtonIconStyle={{ tintColor: ‘white’ }} navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarColor} titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleColor} leftButtonIconStyle = {{ tintColor:‘red’}} title=“”/>
           <Scene key=“Units” component={Units} barButtonIconStyle={{ tintColor: ‘white’ }} navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarColor} titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleColor} /></Scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

What module are you using to handle navigation?

Have you tried https://reactnavigation.org/

With this module, it's quite straightforward to handling this.

Comment: I am using react-native-router-flux

Comment: Are you using V3 or V4 of react-native-router-flux? For V4, you really only need to call Actions.pop().

Comment: I am using V4, Action.pop() navigates to the back scene but I need to perform some action before navigating for(e.g) display a popup while navigating